# concat 2 mini audio files and make a loop and add a background music

Tags: ffmpeg

I Need to concatenate 2 small audio files with loop and add background music in a single command.

I am capable to concatenate two audio files with a background music. My above given code is working.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -i background.mp3 
-filter_complex "[0:0][1:0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1,volume=1dB,aformat=fltp, pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c0[a0]; 
[2]volume=0.5dB,aformat=fltp,pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c1[a1];[a0][a1]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest,aformat=fltp[a]"
-map "[a]" -strict -2 -y output.mp3
```

but i want to a make a loop of the concatenated files till the end of the background music. background music is longer than approx 5 times from concatenated files.

If someone can suggest a single command solution.

I know about amovie tag but unfortunately its not possible to use in here because amovie requires file name which is not possible with concatenated files as per my knowledge.

Can anyone help me how can i achieve my goal!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the concat demuxer.

Create a text file

```
file 1.mp3
file 2.mp3
```

and then,

```
ffmpeg -f concat -stream_loop -1 -i list.txt -i background.mp3 
-filter_complex "[0]volume=1dB,aformat=fltp,pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c0[a0]; 
                 [1]volume=0.5dB,aformat=fltp,pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c1[a1];
                 [a0][a1]amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest,aformat=fltp[a]"
-map "[a]" -strict -2 -y output.mp3
```

Both 1.mp3 and 2.mp3 should have the same properties - sampling rate, channel layout..etc

Comment: what if i say that 1.mp3 is taken via pipe protocol? is it possible to do now?

Comment: The input has to be a seekable, reusable resource, so no.