# FFMpeg joining audio files together, and the last file as the background

Tags: php, audio, ffmpeg, background, contacts

I would like all audio files to be joined together and I always want the last audio file to be background.
I found an SSH command ready to do this but it only suits 3 audio files.
I wish it would work every time no matter how many audio files I put in.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -i background.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1,volume=1dB,aformat=fltp,pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c1[a0];[2]volume=0.5dB,aformat=fltp,pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c1[a1];[a0][a1]amerge,aformat=fltp[a]" -map "[a]" -strict -2 -y final.mp3
```

It would be best if it could be done using the php script and some library.

I found a solution to my problem here, but I would also like to make the background audio play to the end and not get cut off.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57533505/10013762

Comment: Is background.mp3 always longer than the combined duration of 1.mp3 and 2.mp3?